# Update table by replacing string in one column with a substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 id | name                        | color
----|-----------------------------|-------
 1  | some string?12345           | red
 2  | another string?843          | red
 3  | and another string?84930283 | blue
```

I need to update the name column for all rows to remove the '?' and everything after it. So the end result should be:

```
 id | name               | color
----|--------------------|-------
 1  | some string        | red
 2  | another string     | red
 3  | and another string | blue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`split_part`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

```
 SELECT split_part(name, '?', 1)
 FROM mytable
```

To `UPDATE` you can use:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET name = split_part(name, '?', 1)
WHERE strpos(name, '?') <> 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1696b/1)

Comment: Do you need the last line (`WHERE strpos(name, '?') <> 0`)? What would happen if I didn't use that line?

Comment: @Senju You need it so to avoid redundant updates. If you don't use it the result will be the same but the update operation might take longer to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe... just to add another approach:

```
SQL> update table set name = substring(name from '^[^?]*') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT` and `POSITION` string functions. Official **[link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)**

To view the result

```
Select id, LEFT(name,POSITION('?' in name)-1) as Name, Color
From Yourtable
```

To `update`

```
Update Yourtable 
SET name = LEFT(name,POSITION('?' in name)-1)
Where POSITION('?' in name)> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the question: [String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html)

**Offtopic, do not read anythig below.**

In the beginning there were prehistoric people who passed knowledge verbally.

Then there were books and everyone who have access to them can gain knowledge from them.

Then came the Google and everybody were able to get an answer to the well-asked question.

Then came the StackOverflow and anybody were able to ask somebody to ask Google and get answer from them for some rewards.

What is next?